# AMD USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller unstable

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-controller

With a most innocent move of unplugging my Logitech wireless keyboard dongle, a whole storm of USB errors starting happening on my system. I got a BSOD and when I rebooted I saw that the **AMD USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller** was no longer working properly for some reason. There is also some USB root Hub error as well that can be seen when opening the Device Manager:

[image]

When I say 'no longer working' I mean the devices have icons next to them to show they are not functioning, and any USB device plugged into the back of my machine is turning off and on constantly.

**About the Driver**

Driver Name: usbxhci.inf
Class Guid: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
Driver Date: 10/13/2022
Driver Version: 10.0.19041.2193
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: Generic.Install.NT
Driver Rank: 0x802006
Matching Device Id: PCI\CC_0C0330
Outranked Drivers:
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1484&SUBSYS_14841022&REV_00\3&11583659&0&41

**What I have done to troubleshoot**

What I have done to troubleshoot and try to remedy the issue is to uninstall both devices and restart Windows. Sometimes one of them is working ok, perhaps for only a few minutes, then the trouble starts again; the Controller goes in and out of being functional, and I am bombarded with messages about my USB devices not working etc.

I am not sure how to remedy this as I have already:

- uninstalled the Controllers and rebooted (no fix here)
- searched for new drivers (no better drivers found)
- performed a System Restore to a point before this issue started (no dice)
- Windows Repair Install (drastic, yet still issue is present)

Any insights on how to fix this? I certainly need to be able to connect to my computer with USB.

Running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044

Comment: Look inside the connector socket for broken pins or shorting contacts or just general debris in the port. I've seen USB ports go bad over the years with some where pins got bent back in the socket and stopped the machine booting at all, others where plugging in a USB stick would cause an immediate power down. Or you might have accidentally wiggled the connector when pulling it out and shorted power and data briefly, or you might have touched the metal and given it an electrostatic shock while removing. USB might be good, but it is not 100% immune to physical or electrical damage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm inclined to think this is a hardware issue too because a Repair Install still didn't fix it. Is there a way to diagnose the hardware? How do I know which port it is?

Comment: Most likely the one you've disconnected the dongle from, because otherwise you'd have these issues sooner

Comment: EDIT - I do remember testing out several rear USB ports and felt that they werent working. My guess now is that there is some hardware inside (perhaps something that powers these ports) that got fried or something? How do I diagnose this?